# Gmail displaying gaps between images in email signature sent from Outlook but outlook it displays 100%

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

Hi I've designed multiple image signature in html to make all images in the email signature clickable link. i.e A opens email, B Calls the main number etc...

In outlook or in ios mail is shows 100% and works without any gaps between images but in gmail it shows gaps between images when sending from outlook?

Can someone please assist me on a solution on how to fix this. Please see below on what the email signature should look like, how it displays in gmail and the code, TIA.

[What email signature should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6R4W.jpg)

[How is displays in gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryYF3.jpg)

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Jane Doe Email Signature</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" width="650" height="150" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 60px">
            <a href="mailto:janedoe@abc.com" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/5YrTS6W/Image-01.jpg" width="650" height="60" alt"janedoe@abc.com" border="0" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 20px">
            <a href="Tel:+27123456789" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/gT9BDxr/Image-02.jpg" width="650" height="20" alt="+27 (0) 12 345 6789" border="0" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 20px">
            <a href="Tel:+2712345678" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/J3Yh5LY/Image-03.jpg" width="650" height="20" alt="" border="0" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 20px">
            <a href="mailto:janedoe@abc.com" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/w4ZSYT6/Image-04.jpg" width="650" height="20" alt="janedoe@abc.com" border="0" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 10px">
            <a href="https://www.abc.om" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/nzbygZV/Image-05.jpg" width="650" height="10" alt="" border="0" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 20px">
            <a href="" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/4SQfvbB/Image-06.jpg" width="650" height="20" alt="Head Office" border="0" style="display:block; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some attributes may not be supported by the Word editor used by Outlook to display and edit message bodies. For example, `marginheight` is not supported. You can find the supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.